# Wijemo event calender bind to angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, componentone, wijmo

I'm trying to bind the wijeval to an array of events in an angularjs Controller.
This is what if tried so far:

View:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <wijevcal viewtype="week" eventsdata="{{events}}">
    </wijevcal>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["wijmo"]);
function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.events = [{ id: "ev1", subject: "First event", start: new Date(2013, 5, 23, 15, 30), end: new Date(2013, 5, 23, 17, 35) },
      { id: "ev2", subject: "Second event", start: new Date(2013, 5, 23, 10, 30), end: new Date(2013, 5, 23, 11, 35) }];
}
```

The eventsdata binding is not working and if I create a new event it's stored in the local browser stroage.
I hope somebody can help me to get the binding work because the "documentation" I found is terrible

Link to documentation: http://wijmo.com/5/docs/topic/wijmo.angular.WjCalendar.Class.html

Ceddy

Comment: try `<wijevcal viewtype="week" events-data="{{events}}">`

Comment: sadly the calendar stays empty

Comment: where do you see `eventsdata` anyway in the docs? seems you need to pass init data in the constructor options or call `initialize(options)`

Comment: Maybe you are right but I' never calling an constructor for the wijeval, I don't really remember where i found the "eventsdata", it's some month ago when I worked on it.

Comment: Well, then call `initialize(options)` on your cal and set the data in your controller

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using WijEvcal widget of Wijmo 3 and not WjCalendar of Wijmo 5. Here is correct code for using WijEvcal widget with AngularJS:

```
<wij-evcal id="evcal" time-interval="30" style="min-height: 300px" events-data="eventsData" selected-date="selectedDate">
           </wij-evcal>


$scope.eventsData = [{ id: "appt1", subject: "app1", start: new Date(2015, 2, 23, 15, 30), end: new Date(2015, 2, 23, 17, 35) },
                { id: "appt2", subject: "app2", start: new Date(2015, 2, 13, 10, 30), end: new Date(2013, 2, 13, 11, 35) }
            ];
            $scope.selectedDate = new Date(2015, 2, 23);
```

If you want to use Wijmo 5 control then you can refer to the following link:
http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/Scheduler/Scheduler/#/